# isomorphism $H_{n}\left(S^{n}, \Delta_{2}^{n}\right) \stackrel{\approx}{\longleftarrow} H_{n}\left(\Delta_{1}^{n}, \partial \Delta_{1}^{n}\right)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was reading Hatcher's algebraic topology book in page 125,example 2.23 needs the following isomoprhism :

$$\tilde{H}_{n}\left(S^{n}\right) \stackrel{\approx}{\longrightarrow} H_{n}\left(S^{n}, \Delta_{2}^{n}\right) \stackrel{\approx}{\longleftarrow} H_{n}\left(\Delta_{1}^{n}, \partial \Delta_{1}^{n}\right)$$

Where $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are two n-simplices with boundary indentified togother that preserving the order of the vertices that together forms the sphere.

In order to construct the second arrow.We first construct the isomorphism in the chain level,which means $$C_{n}\left(S^{n}, \Delta_{2}^{n}\right) \stackrel{\approx}{\longleftarrow} C_{n}\left(\Delta_{1}^{n}, \partial \Delta_{1}^{n}\right)$$
To construct this one we need the universal property for the quotient group,i,e, To show the map $$C_n(\Delta_1)\to C_n(S^n)\to C_n(S^n,\Delta_2)\tag{*}$$

has kernel $C_n(\partial\Delta_1)$ and it's onto.

I was stuck in showing that the above map (*) is onto.Do we need subdivision to prove it's onto?

I try to handle it alternatively,using the excision,but I found that exsicion needs the interor of $\Delta_1,\Delta_2$ covers the $S^n$,this condition does not hold here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
(*) is not onto: consider a simplex whose image intersects both $\Delta^n_i.$ Interiors of $\Delta^n_i$ also don't cover the sphere, of course. As Hatcher says, the second isomorphism follows from the fact that $S^n / \Delta^n_2 \simeq \Delta_{1}^{n}/ \partial \Delta_{1}^{n}.$ (It is induced by inclusion because the homeomorphism between the latter comes from inclusion
\begin{CD}
\partial \Delta_{1}^{n} @>>> \Delta_{2}^{n} \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\Delta_{1}^{n} @>>> S^n \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\Delta_{1}^{n}/\partial \Delta_{1}^{n} @>>> S^n/\Delta_{2}^{n}
\end{CD}
)

Comment: thank you as a Corollary,$C_{n}\left(S^{n}, \Delta_{2}^{n}\right) \stackrel{\approx}{\longleftarrow} C_{n}\left(\Delta_{1}^{n}, \partial \Delta_{1}^{n}\right)
$ does not holds correct,since  it does not maps onto?

Comment: @yi li The $($inclusion$)_\#$ is not an isomorphism, yes.